# How to best implement user-specific logic in a Spring web application?

Tags: spring, workflow

I'm facing the following problem: the Spring web application I'm building is pretty user-specific. Each user might have some pieces of the logic tailored to their needs.
I'm wondering how to best implement such a 'framework' that would allow for easy injecting of new users along with their specific logic.

I'm thinking of one the following solutions:

- Providing a common interface for all users and invoking the actual user-specific implementations via reflection. Then, when adding a new user, I just need to write the logic, compile it and put the *.class file onto the server
- Using some sort of an XML-configurable rule/workflow engine. I can build the individual blocks of logic upfront and then when a new user shows up I just specify an XML (Spring config) describing the logic flow

The first solution seems initially easier but requires more work when adding a new user. The second takes more time to develop the rule/workflow mechanism, but then adding a new user should be simpler.

What do you think? Any other ideas? Do you know any frameworks/patterns that would help me in this task?

Thanks, 
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the first solution (Interface and programming) but it has some draw backs:

- it is not very secure (the user specific code can do anything)
- you need to add some compiled files to the class path

I would try use some scripting language (Java Script for example). So a privileged user can upload the scripts via the fronted. The scripts can be stored in the database, so you can update the application without fear to delete the files.

And the second good thing is, that it is may possible to restrict the functions that the script can invoke.

Comment: Ralph, thanks for the tips :) Fortunately the user-specific code is not really written by the user but by us (based on the user's requirements) so security is not really an issue.